# slow response from php code at vps

Tags: php, html, postgresql, wamp, windows-server-2012-r2

i have simple site on some vps. i used wamp server and additional setup postgresql instead mysql. site works fast on localhost and from public ip, but...

i have webix grid on one page and php file put data from database into this grid, when page are loading. when i on localhost, grid loading time is 5 sec. I think for 35k row its not bad. But when i loaded page from web via another pc, loading time grow 4-5 times - above 20 second.

internet connection is fast, it looks like some server setting slow down transfering data from php or executing php code. I had same problem with transfering files on server from ftp, and solve it via disabling some checking options in server.

Here is my php code

```
require_once("../codebase/data_connector.php");
require_once("../codebase/db_postgre.php");
$conn_string = "host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=demo user=postgres password=postgres";
$dbconn = pg_pconnect($conn_string);
$dbtype = "Postgre";
$data = new JSONDataConnector($dbconn, $dbtype);
//$data->dynamic_loading(35);
$data->render_sql("SELECT id,count,contragent,value,inn,kpp FROM mart_customers", "id", "count, contragent, value, inn, kpp");
pg_close($dbconn);
```

Do anybody have idea, what problem can be now? i tried do some famous thing, like change localhost on 127.0.0.1 and add apache into firewall  exclusion, but nothing changed.

My options: windows server 2012 R2 + wamp + postgreSQL

Comment: Dont use wamp for a prod environment, use IIS instead if you use windows

Comment: i tried to switch to iss, but problem still alive. on localhost time loading - 5 sec, from another pc - 30 second.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you use a development environment which matches your production/live environment as closely as possible.

For this, you could use VirtualBox (https://www.virtualbox.org/) which allows you to spin up a guest machine on your host in which you can use any OS, server, etc together with any dependencies on a project by project basis. There are others but I've only got experience with the VB so can't comment on others.

Try using Vagrant together with VirtualBox: https://www.vagrantup.com/. Vagrant makes the provisioning of your virtual environments easy and reproducible without much effort.